# jQueryMobile pageinit and ajax

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova

right now i have this code using phonegap and jquerymobile

```
$( '#user_detail' ).live( 'pageinit',function(event) {
    $.ajax({ 
        url: 'http://localhost/get_user.php',
        success: function(txt) {
            $("#details").append(txt);
        }
    });
}
```

However, when data is updated server side, the changes isn't reflected. Anyone can point me what is wrong? Is it because of caching as i have tried to set cache as false on ajax.

If the android application is closed and open, data is populated

Edited,

Right now, once phonegap application is loaded, it gets all the data onto `#details` **however when there is changes to on `get_user.php` the data is not reflected and i have to close the application and reopen back in android for the changes to be updated.**

What should i do in order for it to automatically populated as in if I move to other page and forth back and the data should be there.

Thanks.

Comment: I think we need more code, I can't see your ajax callback.

Comment: Are you getting something back but its just not formatted like a JQM styled item? More code please.

Comment: no that issue, this is entirely different as if the changes on json isn't being populated by ajax if the application is not closed and re-opened back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is quite confusing, I can't able to know whether you data is not reflected or your code changes in get_user.php is not reflected.

But I guess problem is a event you have used. use `pageshow` event instead of `pageinit`, I think it will resolve your issue.

```
$( '#user_detail' ).live( 'pageshow',function(event) {
    $.ajax({ 
        url: 'http://localhost/get_user.php',
        success: function(txt) {
            $("#details").append(txt);
        }
    });
}
```